# How to use for loop to collect same values by comparing one element with next one

Tags: python

I want to count how many times a 1.0 appear in array and similarly for 5.0. This I want to do in a for loop without using any build in function such as counter and np.argwhere. I want to compare two values like 1st and second value of a and then add it in a separate list and then I count the length of new list to count their number. I have made several efforts to do it but all are useless.

```
a = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0,5.0])
list=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] not in list:
        list.append(a[i])
print(list)
for j in range(len(list)):
    for k in range(len(a)):
        if a[k] == list[j]:`
```

Comment: The first observation is that you shouldn't be using the name `list` because that's a builtin

Answer (score 0):

Using just a Python dictionary (you already have numpy imported as a dependency). But if you don't want to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you can use `dict.get()` and increment from 0 if the value doesn't already exist as a key.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0,5.0])
my_count = {}

for item in a:
    my_count[item] = my_count.get(item, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use `collections.Counter`? Then it would be simple

```
import collections
collections.Counter(a)
```

If you must reinvent the wheel, using a list isn't very useful, you need to hold a *count* of each *value*. Basically two related values. Best thing for this is a dictionary:

```
result = {}
for elem in a:
    if elem not in result:
        result[elem] = 1
    else:
        result[elem] += 1
```

Even better, use a defaultdict

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(int)
for elem in a:
    result[elem] += 1
```

Comment: I don't want to use built in functions. I first collect unique elements by for loop and then want to apply  another for loop to know that how many times each unique element appear

Comment: @user10163680 this is looking too assignment-y to get a reasonable answer. This answer would be the usual approach, I gave an answer that doesn't require costly multiple iterations and only uses a dictionary. It's pointless for us to give answers useful only for learning the very basics to some contrived task because you should be researching that yourself.